# Does val initialization always allocate memory in scala?

Tags: scala

Imagine I have

```
val a : List[Int] = List.fill(1e7d.toInt)(0)
val b : List[Int] = a
```

Is new memory always allocated when `val b = a`? Or `b` just points to elements stored to `a`? If memory is allocated is it possible to make something like a pointer to not allocate memory for `b` but be able to access to values through it?

Comment: `b` is just a pointer to the same object as `a`.

Comment: "If memory is allocated is it possible to make something like a pointer to not allocate memory for b but be able to access to values through it?" You can use `def` instead of `val` for this.

Answer (score 1):

`new` allocates memory, so everything that underneath calls `new` allocates. For everything else things works like reference type on JVM - if you prefer C++ terminology:

- reference types are like C++ pointers in that they can be `null`s and that assignment operator just copies the address value from one place to another
- reference types are like C++ references in that `a.b` access `b` property/method of object `a` and you **cannot** work directly on underlying memory addresses

In your example `List.fill` has in its implementation `new` so it allocates (it allocates objects that create `List`; elements of this list are created by closure so it depends on closure), while `b` uses local variable (from stack) to store the address copied from `a`.